# MySQL command prompt doesnt require password

Tags: mysql, passwords

I have installed MySQL on my machine. I can log in by directly opening the MySQL 5.6 command line client from the start menu and it prompts me for my password. When I enter the correct password it lets me in, and if it's wrong, it kicks me out.

When I run MySQL from the command prompt, the ONLY way I can log in (using both root user or another user I have created) is to enter no password. If I enter my password it says `access denied to root@localhost`... yada yada ... `using password:YES`

so in summary if i type

```
mysql -u root -p
password: [mypassword]
```

it doesn't work, throwing the error `Access denied, using password yes`

However, if I do

```
mysql -u root -p
password: [blank]
```

it logs in. same behavior for any other user.

That makes no sense to me cause in every other application I have to enter a password to get in.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the user root has no password by default unless specified during installation. Trying to login with a password is impossible *if there is no password.*

Comment: the root user does have a password, and mysql prompts me for that password if i enter mysql through any other means. I have manually reset the root password multiple times now to see if this would address the problem with no success. this ONLY happens when i try to log in to mysql through the command prompt. In this case ANY user with a password will fail to log in unless I do not enter a password.